# Sum of Eigenvectors Entries of an Adjacency Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, random-matrices

I have a question regarding the sums $\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{j}\left(i\right)$ where $v_j$ are eigenvectors of adjacency matrix $A$ which have been normalized to unit length.

Ordering the eigenvectors by their eigenvalues and computing these sums on both random and real-world graphs I noticed that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{1}\left(i\right)>\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{j}\left(i\right)$  for $j\geq2$.

It should be easy to prove that this is always the case but I am currently at a dead end. Are people aware of any results which may be useful?

I am also interested in putting bounds on this difference for random matrices.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. We should assume that the graph is non-bipartite.

Comment: The Perron-Frobenius implies that for a connected graph $v_1$ will have strictly positive entries, which means that all the others will have some negative entries since they are orthogonal to $v_1$. If the graph is regular then $v_1$ is the constant vector and all others are orthogonal to it which means the sum of their entries is 0. This doesn't prove what you want in general though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true in general.  Consider first a graph with two components, one a complete graph on $4$ vertices and the other a cycle on $n-4$ vertices.

Then $v_1$ is the eigenvector for the largest eigenvalue of the complete graph, and sums to $2$, while $v_2$ is the eigenvector for the largest eigenvalue of the cycle, and adds to $\sqrt{n-4}$.

This graph is disconnected, but we can perturb it to a connected graph by adding a single edge without changing things too much.  When I tried this with $n=24$, the largest eigenvalue was $3.10$ and its eigenvector was still mostly supported on the complete graph, with the components adding to $2.26$.  Meanwhile the second largest eigenvalue $\lambda_2=1.98$ had an eigenvector adding to $4.07$.